# Installing an NPM module without installing its dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, package-managers, umd

We have a project that uses NPM as its package manager. We use Webpack to build a Javascript app that is consumed by a Rails app. The app is fully self-contained and is built to a `/dist` directory that is included in the package. For reasons that are out of scope of this question, the Rails app consumes this App as a UMD module, loading it via a script tag and initialising it:

```js
App({})
```

The problem is that the package has a large number of dependencies. When the Rails app installs the package, *it also installs all the package's dependencies*, despite the fact that it doesn't need or use any of these dependencies because everything it needs is present in the App bundle.

**Is there any way the Rails app can install the package (and access the app in the `/dist` directory) without also installing all the package's dependencies?**

Note that we don't want to move all dependencies to the app's `devDependencies` as that will be confusing (and we may well end up with multiple ways of distributing the app, including via es6 import). Also note that we are using Yarn as our package manager.

To clarify, we are using NPM as a means of sharing versioned releases with the Rails app, however the only thing in the package the Rails app cares about is the UMD module. It is very useful for the Rails app to be able to do `yarn add Example@latest` and immediately pull in the latest version of our App, however it doesn't need to resolve the package or its dependencies as they are already baked into the UMD module.

Comment: If you already have the app built in the dist folder using webpack you shouldn't need to install anything with npm at all since webpack has already packaged them together in the bundle. But to answer your question quickly, no there's not a way to do that and you probably shouldn't want to since it would break that packages you are installing. But maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Shimmy568 I was thinking along the same lines. The JS app bundle was included into the project via a `script` tag. So I'm a little unclear as to why there is an installation process.

Comment: @marshy101 We are just using the NPM package as a means of distributing the package to the Rails app. It makes it easy for us to push versioned updates and for the Rails app to consume them. The point is that it is using NPM as a means of installing the package, but only needs the package to get hold of the UMD module, not to install the package and its dependencies, because the package and dependencies are already baked into the UMD module.

Comment: @Undistraction I think understand now. However, as far as I'm concerned, the only way to prevent npm from installing the dependencies is to move them from your package.json either out completely or into dev(which you don't want to do).  Maybe the solution is to manage different package.json for different env - try [penv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/penv)

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.